# Bing Provider in React-Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, bing, react-leaflet

Does anyone have any example code of using Bing maps as the provider with React-Leaflet? I looked through the docs but it only use openstreetmap. I don't see an example of adding any provider.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Bing Maps tiles with Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442055/use-bing-maps-tiles-with-leaflet)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem kinda. I could not use React-Leaflet or at least not version 3 so I did it with React, Leaflet, and leaflet-bing-layer. For my needs I also needed to make an api call to render ferry pins. Rather than type it all in here I will include a link to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tdurant72/81237ce54d3bd1526073e93603a75dc8).